# Data source name not found and no default driver specified (VS & Access)

Tags: odbc, connection-string

i'm using a connectionstring as follows:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};dbq=D:\Year1213\projects\arshad0413\App_Data\Database21.accdb;defaultdir=D:\Year1213\projects\arshad0413\App_Data;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin"
  providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

And I'm getting this error.

Exception Details: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

It works fine on localhost, but when uploaded to server it doesn't work.
What might be causing this?

Comment: Possibly a permissions issue -- locally, your account has access to the db in your d drive.  When published (IIS?) your aspnet user possibly doesn't.

Comment: But when I changed the connectionstring from microsoft access to Microsoft SQL, it works perfectly fine.  Both the access file and the sql file is in the same folder.  So surely I have access on the server.  So maybe access driver isn't installed on the server?

Comment: Can you post your SQL Server connection string that is working for you?  Is it pointing at a D drive file or the server/db instance?  Usually you'd be pointing at the server/db and not a file location when using SQL Server and thus the security is handled differently.  Also, I wonder if this might not help: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `64bit JVM`.use `32bit JVM` instead.
I was facing same problem while using `64bit JVM`, but `32bit jvm` solved my problem.